# Manipulate DateTime and retain original format

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a DateTime string which *I can assume is in a parsable format* using Date.parse() or a 3rd party library. The format could differ based on a user's location and settings. For example, here are some strings I could see: **"2014/08/19 16:10:20"** or **"08/19/2014 4:10:20 PM"**.

I would like to manipulate the time, say by adding 30 minutes, but also preserve the original format string when I present the new time to the user. I suppose I'm looking for something like a parse function that gives you a DateTime along with the format string it detected. Is there an easy way to accomplish this? 3rd party libraries are welcome, with a preference towards jQuery since I'm already using that.

Note: I don't know what the format is going to be before I parse the datetime string. It can be one of many different formats. (However I probably could build a list of possible format strings.)

Comment: Take a look at [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: I recently started working with moment.js and found it really nice http://momentjs.com/. Check the documentation, I believe it covers the functionality you are looking for

Comment: I'm looking at Moment.js right now but I'm not seeing any way of detecting the format.

Comment: Found it! There is a plugin for moment that does what I want: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/parseformat/